# image isn't displayed inside of inputfield

Tags: html, css

I want to create a navigationbar with a inputfield. On the right side (inside the inputfield), I want to display a glass. I have this code here:

```css
*{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

body{
 background-color: rgb(226, 220, 220);
}

nav{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: white;
}

nav > .nav_ul{
 width: 1000px;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

nav > .nav_ul > .nav_li{
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 10px 0px;
}

nav > .nav_ul > .nav_li > .nav_a{
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 7px;
 background-color: #5238DF;
 display: block;
 color: white;
}

nav > .nav_ul > .nav_search{
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}

nav > .nav_ul > .nav_search > .nav_searchfield{
 padding: 7px;
}

nav > .nav_ul > .nav_search > .fa_search{
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="backbone/general.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <nav>
   <ul class="nav_ul">
    <li class="nav_li"><a href="#" class="nav_a">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav_li"><a href="#" class="nav_a">Link 2</a></li>
    <div class="nav_search">
     <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
     <input class="nav_searchfield" type="text" placeholder="Search ..." />
    </div>
    <li class="nav_li"><a href="#" class="nav_a">Link 3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </body>
</html>
```

I use fontawesome for the image, but the image isn't displayed. What did i wrong? Here is a image:

[image]

Comment: [no repro](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yLS51.png). Most likely your browser/OS/both do not support that font.

Comment: I added a image... On localhost I can only see this

Comment: Not relevant. And it's not an image, it's a unicode character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solve your problem:

```
nav > .nav_ul > .nav_search > .nav_searchfield{
    padding: 7px 28px 7px 7px;
}

nav > .nav_ul > .nav_search > .fa-search{
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/k433otdg/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Its perfect. But I still can't see the glass.

Comment: You need to add the styles come with font-awesome to use it. Example: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css

Answer (score 1):

Set a custom margin for the icon. `.fa-margin { margin-left: -20px; }`

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  background-color: rgb(226, 220, 220);
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
nav > .nav_ul {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
nav > .nav_ul > .nav_li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
nav > .nav_ul > .nav_li > .nav_a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px;
  background-color: #5238DF;
  display: block;
  color: white;
}
nav > .nav_ul > .nav_search {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
nav > .nav_ul > .nav_search > .nav_searchfield {
  padding: 7px;
}
nav > .nav_ul > .nav_search > .fa_search {} .fa-margin {
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="backbone/general.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav_ul">
      <li class="nav_li"><a href="#" class="nav_a">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav_li"><a href="#" class="nav_a">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <div class="nav_search">

        <input class="nav_searchfield" type="text" placeholder="Search ..."><span class="fa fa-search fa-margin"></span> 

      </div>
      <li class="nav_li"><a href="#" class="nav_a">Link 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```